# export data to the excel from multiple tables in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, excel, codeigniter

I want to export the data into excel form the multiple tables i wrote logic as per my requirements for those three tables and kept in a single function in the model. and i'm calling this function in controller, I've done this method for only one table but not for multiple tables

```
This is MODAL
function update_wallet_pbo(){
$query1 = $this->db->query(" SELECT * FROM privilege_customer WHERE accountStatus = 'A' ");
     $sno = 1;
      if($query1->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach($query1->result() as $row1){
                $acc = $row1->accountNum;
                $PBONum = $row1->PBONum;
                echo 'S no. - '.$sno.' PBO No. = '.$PBONum.' Acc No. = '.$acc.'<br/>';
                $total_balance = 0 ;

                $query3 = $this->db->query(" SELECT * FROM `pbo_purchase_wallet` WHERE PBONum = '$PBONum' ORDER by date ASC ");
                if($query3->num_rows() > 0){
                    foreach($query3->result() as $row3){
                        if($row3->type == 'Credited'){
                            $total_balance = round( floatval($total_balance) , 2 ) + round( floatval($row3->transactionAmount) , 2 );

                            echo 'ID = '.$row3->id.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; PS no. = '.$row3->PSNum.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Credit = '.$row3->transactionAmount.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Debit = 0 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Balance Amount = '.$row3->totalAmount.' &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Actual Balance Amount = '.$total_balance.'<br/>';
                        }
                        else if($row3->type == 'Debited'){
                            $total_balance = round( floatval($total_balance) , 2 ) - round( floatval($row3->transactionAmount) , 2 );

                            echo 'ID = '.$row3->id.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; PS no. = '.$row3->PSNum.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Credit = 0 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Debit = '.$row3->transactionAmount.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Balance Amount = '.$row3->totalAmount.' &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Actual Balance Amount = '.$total_balance.'<br/>';
                        }

                        /*$data = array( 'totalAmount' => $total_balance);
                        $this->db->update('stockist_sales_wallet_additions', $data);*/
                    }
                }

                $query4 = $this->db->query(" SELECT * FROM `pbo_wallet` WHERE PBONum = '$PBONum' ");
                if($query4->num_rows() > 0){
                    foreach($query4->result() as $row4){
                        $purchase_wallet = round( floatval($row4->purchaseWallet) , 2 );
                        if($purchase_wallet <= $total_balance+1 && $purchase_wallet >= $total_balance-1){
                            echo '<b style="color:blue;">---------------------------Correct-----------------------</b><br/>';

                            echo 'Purchase Wallet = '.$purchase_wallet.'&nbsp;&nbsp;Total Balance = '.$total_balance.'<br/>';

                            echo '<b style="color:blue;">---------------------------Correct-----------------------</b><br/>';
                        }
                        else{
                            echo '<b style="color:red;">---------------------------Wrong-----------------------</b><br/>';

                            echo 'Purchase Wallet = '.$purchase_wallet.'&nbsp;&nbsp;Total Balance = '.$total_balance.'<br/>';

                            echo '<b style="color:red;">---------------------------Wrong-----------------------</b>';
                        }
                    }
                }

                $sno++;
                echo '<br/><br/><br/>';

                if($sno == 10){
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my controller

```
        function update_wallet_pbo(){           
        $this->load->model("AdminModel");
        $this->load->library("excel");
        $object = new PHPExcel();

        $object->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        $table_columns = array("Name", "Address", );

        $column = 0;

        foreach($table_columns as $field)
        {
         $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column, 1, $field);
         $column++;
        }

        $employee_data = $this->AdminModel->update_wallet_pbo();

        $excel_row = 2;

        foreach($employee_data as $row)
        {
         $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $excel_row, 'dsf');
         $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $excel_row, 'sadf');

         $excel_row++;
        }

        $object_writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($object, 'Excel5');
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Employee Data.xls"');
        $object_writer->save('php://output');
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem with all that code?

Comment: Suppose if i am fetching only one query " SELECT * FROM `pbo_purchase_wallet"  in above modal it works fine but i am fetching the data from three tables as one function in modal there is the problem and not exporting the data to excel

Comment: That should not be a problem after all, if you restructure your code to work with three different tables. After all, what is that modal for, why do you echo so much stuff to get an Excel export?

Comment: I'm just printing out without excel. that's why i'm using the echo

Comment: And still, what's the problem? Couldn't you wrap the controller part in a `for` loop to access different databases and print them to different sheets?